# Compute variable according to factor levels

Tags: r, data-conversion

I am kind of new to R and programming in general. I am currently strugling with a piece of code for data transformation and hope someone can take a little bit of time to help me.

Below a reproducible exemple :

```
#    Data
a <- c(rnorm(12, 20))
b <- c(rnorm(12, 25))
f1 <- rep(c("X","Y","Z"), each=4) #family
f2 <- rep(x = c(0,1,50,100), 3) #reference and test levels

dt <- data.frame(f1=factor(f1), f2=factor(f2), a,b)

#library loading
library(tidyverse)
```

Goal : Compute all values (`a`,`b`) using a reference value. Calculation should be : `a/a_ref`  with `a_ref = a` when `f2=0` depending on the family (`f1` can be X,Y or Z).

I tried to solve this by using this code :

```
    test <- filter(dt, f2!=0) %>% group_by(f1) %>%
    mutate("a/a_ref"=a/(filter(dt, f2==0) %>% group_by(f1) %>% distinct(a) %>% pull))
```

I get :

[test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5lhG.png)

as you can see `a` is divided by `a_ref`. But my script seems to recycle the use of reference values (`a_ref`) regardless of the family `f1`.

Do you have any suggestion so `A` is computed with regard of the family (`f1`) ?

Thank you for reading !

---

**EDIT**

I found a way to do it 'manualy'

```
   filter(dt, f1=="X") %>% mutate("a/a_ref"=a/(filter(dt, f1=="X" & f2==0) %>% distinct(a) %>% pull()))
      f1  f2        a        b         a/a_ref
    1  X   0 21.77605 24.53115 1.0000000
    2  X   1 20.17327 24.02512 0.9263973
    3  X  50 19.81482 25.58103 0.9099366
    4  X 100 19.90205 24.66322 0.9139422
```

the problem is that I'd have to update the code for each variable and family and thus is not a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# use this to reproduce the same dataset and results
set.seed(5)

# Data
a <- c(rnorm(12, 20))
b <- c(rnorm(12, 25))
f1 <- rep(c("X","Y","Z"), each=4) #family
f2 <- rep(x = c(0,1,50,100), 3) #reference and test levels

dt <- data.frame(f1=factor(f1), f2=factor(f2), a,b)

#library loading
library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
  group_by(f1) %>%                 # for each f1 value
  mutate(a_ref = a[f2 == 0],       # get the a_ref and add it in each row
         "a/a_ref" = a/a_ref) %>%  # divide a and a_ref
  ungroup() %>%                    # forget the grouping
  filter(f2 != 0)                  # remove rows where f2 == 0

# # A tibble: 9 x 6
#       f1     f2        a        b    a_ref `a/a_ref`
#   <fctr> <fctr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1      X      1 21.38436 24.84247 19.15914 1.1161437
# 2      X     50 18.74451 23.92824 19.15914 0.9783583
# 3      X    100 20.07014 24.86101 19.15914 1.0475490
# 4      Y      1 19.39709 22.81603 21.71144 0.8934042
# 5      Y     50 19.52783 25.24082 21.71144 0.8994260
# 6      Y    100 19.36463 24.74064 21.71144 0.8919090
# 7      Z      1 20.13811 25.94187 19.71423 1.0215013
# 8      Z     50 21.22763 26.46796 19.71423 1.0767671
# 9      Z    100 19.19822 25.70676 19.71423 0.9738257
```

You can do this for more than one variable using:

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(f1) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(a:b), funs(./.[f2 == 0])) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Or generally use `vars(a:z)` to use all variables between `a` and `z` as long as they are one after the other in your dataset.

Another solution could be using `mutate_if` like:

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(f1) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(./.[f2 == 0])) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Where the function will be applied to all numeric variables you have. The variables `f1` and `f2` will be factor variables, so it just excludes those ones.

Comment: I've added the `a_ref` column to make sure I calculated it in the correct way (based on what you mentioned). If the process looks correct I can remove it.

Comment: I didn't think about creating a new variable refering to the reference value ! thank you very much. Any Idea how I can compute these on all values (a & b), in my actual case I have 40 variables ...

Comment: Do you mean you're going to use a_ref, b_ref, etc?

Comment: You can do the same without creating that column using `dt %>%
  group_by(f1) %>%                
  mutate("a/a_ref" = a/a[f2 == 0]) %>%  
  ungroup() %>%              
  filter(f2 != 0)`

Comment: I found a way to do this automaticaly on all my variables : `dt %>% group_by(f1) %>% mutate_at(funs(./.[f2 == 0]), .vars=c(3:4)) %>% ungroup()` Thank you for your help

Comment: That's a great solution. Unfortunately I didn't have free time to work on this. I see you're using the columns position in .vars . Check how to select variables by name in case the position changes in the future. Apart from that comment your solution looks great!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, as new to Rprograming its really encouraging. Regarding the variable names I tied something like `.vars=c("a":"b")` but it didn't work :/

Comment: Your solution with `.vars=c(3:4)` doesn't work for me. Try `dt %>% 
  group_by(f1) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(a:b), funs(./.[f2 == 0])) %>% 
  ungroup()` to use variable names, or use `dt %>% 
  group_by(f1) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(./.[f2 == 0])) %>% 
  ungroup()` to mutate only numeric variables, because `f1` and `f2` will be factor variables.